# Is there a direct way to concatenate two char arrays (char*)?

Tags: c++

I know I can construct strings out of them and simply use operator+.
But I need to pass the concatenated char array to and old C function so I can't do that.

Comment: Are you aware that std::string has a member function called `c_str()` which yields a `const char*` as a pointer-to the first character in your string?

Comment: No I wasn't... That solves everything !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can do it with `std::string`

   ```
   std::string s1 = "Hello", s2 = "World";
   std::string s3 = s1 + s2;
   const char* c_data = s3.c_str( ); // pointer to char array
   ```
2. You can do it with [strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) function

Answer (score 0):

If you are interacting with C code, you likely want your strings to be allocated with `malloc()` rather than with `new`: there is a number of nice functions available in C which produce malloc'ed strings. One of them is `asprintf()`, which you can easily use to concatenate your strings:

```
char* foo = ..., *bar = ..., *result;
asprintf(&result, "%s%s", foo, bar);

baz(result);    //Use the concatenated string.

free(result);    //cleanup
```

The nice thing about this approach is, that it is quite safe: Since `asprintf()` allocates a buffer to fit your string, there is no danger of overrunning buffers as with `strcat()`, `strcpy()`, and friends.

Note, however, that even though  `asprintf()` conforms to the POSIX-2008 standard, it is not part of the C standard, so it's not available everywhere. All Linux systems have it, though.